# BLToolkit - is it able to make async database operation?

Tags: bltoolkit

I want to avoid blocking the executing thread by slow database read , and I like BLToolkit **DataAccessor** very much

```
public abstract class PersonAccessor : DataAccessor
{
    [SqlText(@"SELECT * FROM Person WHERE FirstName = @firstName")]
    public abstract List<Person> GetPersonListByFirstName(string @firstName);

    [SprocName("sp_GetPersonListByLastName")]
    public abstract List<Person> GetPersonListByLastName(string @lastName);
}
```

Is it possible to use async operation for BLToolkit DataAccessor?

Hope it is able to return `Task<T>` and I can use `await` from C# 5.0

Br.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may combine the [Async](https://github.com/igor-tkachev/bltoolkit/wiki/Aspects.Async) attribute which provides the Begin End pattern and [turn it into Task](http://www.justjuzzy.com/2012/10/turn-iasyncresult-code-into-await-keyword/) like this (not tested) :

```
public abstract class PersonAccessor : DataAccessor
{
    [SqlText(@"SELECT * FROM Person WHERE FirstName = @firstName")]
    public abstract List<Person> GetPersonListByFirstName(string @firstName);

    [Async]
    public abstract IAsyncResult BeginGetPersonListByFirstName(string @firstName, AsyncCallback callback, object state);

    [Async]
    public abstract List<Person> EndGetPersonListByFirstName(IAsyncResult asyncResult);

    public Task<List<Person>> GetPersonListByFirstNameAsync(string @firstName)
    {
        return Task.Factory.FromAsync(
            BeginGetPersonListByFirstName(),
            EndGetPersonListByFirstName,
            @firstName, 
            null);
    }
}

public class TestClass 
{
    public List<Person> AwaitTest(PersonAccessor personAccessor, string @firstName)
    {
        return await personAccessor.GetPersonListByFirstNameAsync(@firstName);
    }
}
```